# npm browserify : safari unexpected token

Tags: npm, safari, browserify

I m running npm and browserify, ok on FF and Chrome, Safari complains with an unexpected token on the bundle.js:

var PIXI = require("pixi.js");

I tried to replace `'` with `"`but no success. I don't think it is related to pixi, it gave me same problem in requiring other libraries, in one case replacing with double quotes worked but not now.

I don't get the problem.

Running Safari Version 7.1.8 and do not want to update, since I don't want to update whole operating system for a browser..

Comment: What is the stack trace from Safari's web console?

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('` but the error is displayed in lines that has no error with other browsers e.g. `module.exports = function (graph, settings) {`

Comment: Yikes! Safari 7.1.8 was released on 13 August 2015, however, Pixi.js advertises support for Safari 2.0+ so we should be okay. I have my doubts that they really test that far back but anyway let's try working the problem! Open up a new terminal and follow: https://gist.github.com/casr/454a59e13cf1c1f031a47a4d9b3e9b79

Report back if it works :)

Comment: hi @casr, I know I don't want to update whole operating system to update a browser ! :| - not about Pixi, safari console is buggy, sometimes a blank page but no error is given, sometimes the line about the error is incorrect. Turns out the issue was with objects not supported on safari, had to scratch my head to use polyfills. I thought the code was not completely parsed, because an ECMA6 object was not supported and exited; but "unexpected token" was far from being informative. The problem of a buggy debugging tool persists.

Comment: Ah if you're using ES6/ES2015 you will need to compile it down to ES5 or ES3 to support Safari 7. With browserify you can use babelify.

Comment: could you should how to compile down ? should I compile down the bundle or import a module via request? I read babelify may have issues with Proxy objects.

Comment: I found this polyfill for proxy objects: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill . Might be worth a try?

Comment: yes I solve it with a ployfill and also using traps within the handler object  `handler = { get(target, value) // this syntax is not supported, get: function(target, value) // this is supported} `. However, really difficult to debug: the errors displayed in console do not provide right suggestions and wrong line number. And functions like `path.aStar(graph, {
 // distance is not recognised as  a property ?
 //   distance(fromNode, toNode, link) { 
  //     return link.data.proximity;
  //   }
  // });` are not supported - FYI see this beautiful module https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.path